# How to convert parts of a line to uppercase in a file

Tags: bash, shell, perl, sh

I have a file `file.txt` and it has the lines below. I want the queuename to be converted to uppercase, like this: `queuename=SP00245B`

```
    # Queue name
    #
    queuename=sp00245b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$1 == "queuename" {$2 = toupper($2)}1' FS== OFS== input-file
```

Note that this will fail if there are 2 `=` in the line, and only the values between the first 2 `=` will be uppercased.  If that's an issue, it's an easy fix (left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: Thanks for your help, the queuename will always be "queuename='any 8 digit name with combination of [a-z] and [0-9]'". Is there any way to make the changes inside the file(file.txt) in the same command line, instead of redirecting it to a different file and move back . Thanks again.

Comment: You really don't want to make the changes directly in the file.  Doing so provides you with no "escape hatch" and can easily lead to loss of data.  Filtering your data to a temporary file and then overwriting the original data is the proper (TM) way to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

A simple Perl solution:

```
perl -i -pe 's/^\s*queuename=\K(.*)/\U$1/' file.txt
```

(Remove `-i` if you don't want to modify the file in place.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `sed` conversion `\U` to convert the portions of the matched pattern with the substitution command to uppercase. To covert everything following the `'='` sign you could use, e.g.

```
sed '/^queuename=/s/=.*$/\U&/' filename
```

To edit the file in-place, include the `-i` option, e.g.

```
sed -i '/^queuename=/s/=.*$/\U&/' filename
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "queuename=sp00245b" | sed '/^queuename=/s/=.*$/\U&/'
queuename=SP00245B
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -i 's/\(^[[:blank:]]*queuename=\)\(.*\)/\1\U\2/' file.txt
```

This uses two captures groups and the `\U` sequence to toggle uppercase substitution for the second group.